# Where is 'for' of the for loop is defined? Like cout is object of iostream is 'for' or 'while' also an object?

Tags: c++, loops

as all the syntax terms must be defined in the program where is for defined.

ex: 
for  (i=0;i<8;i++0)
{  }

how does the compiler understand and decide the course of action after it encounters the for keyword.

Comment: `for` is a keyword.  keywords means special things in the language.

Comment: its a keyword and part of the language, `cout` is a library function defined in the standard library and not part of the core language

Comment: It's defined [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.for). In the standard like every keyword like `if`, `int` and `return`.

Comment: @NathanOliver  I understand that for is a keyword but leads me to another question Where is the keyword defined in the language, at compiler level ?

Comment: It is defined in [the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/).  The standard tells the compiler how it should behave and the the compiler, once it sees the keyword, stamps out the machine code needed to do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where is 'for' of the for loop is defined?

The meaning of a `for` statement is defined in the standard document that describes the language. In the sections [stmt.iter] and [stmt.for] in particular.

> how does the compiler understand and decide the course of action after it encounters the for keyword.

A compiler does not "understand". A compiler is a computer program. It is a sequence of instructions for a computer. The processor executes the instructions depending on input given to it.

The programmers who implement the compiler make sure that the compiler produces a program that behaves as the language specifies.

If you want to know more in depth, then you are essentially asking, how compilers are written. That is outside the scope of my answer. You'll find that books have been written about the subject.